# webAPI 2.1 response to angular API call sometime take more than 5 min

Tags: angular, ajax, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, angular8

In web application with api calls to WebApI from angular 8 normally takes 4-5 secs. But on some events it takes more than 5 mins for response to reach angular which should normally not take more than 10 sec. There is no delay on serverside. I can see the IIS response of 3200 for the same call much before it reaches Angular. It is working fine on local but only on servers the issue is occurring. Even the API which shows this behavior is not specific as any API shows this.

Comment: How much time does it take when you request from Postman? This would help in diagnosing the problem Is it a single endpoint that takes more time or all the endpoints take more time? I would suggest you add more information about the API endpoint process.

Comment: Make request from Postman and edit the question. Add info about where is the problem in the Angular App or the API.